# emit text at cursor position (awesome-wm)

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I was planning to remap my copy/paste keys on awesome-wm to be more similar to my mac for a while, since it doesn't interfere with terminal's ctrl+c command and doesn't require the use of shift. Today I finally stopped being lazy and slapped something together that I expected to work:

```
awful.key({ modkey,         }, "c", function () os.execute('xsel -p -o | xsel -i -b') end),
awful.key({ modkey,         }, "v", function ()
    local handle = io.popen('xsel -ob')
    local result = handle:read('*a')
    handle:close()
    return result
end),
```

The copy part works fine, the paste does not. I realize that instead of "return"ing the result, I should emit it, insert that text at mouse position (or if I could just trigger ctrl+v that would be good enough too). I know result contains the text I want, I used naughty.notify to check, but I'm clueless about how to emit it. Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts#Key_binding_for_X-selection-paste